# How to determine configuration in Swift code using Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm creating an application using Swift Package Manager and I need to know the configuration of which the project was built under, i.e `Debug` or `Release`. I'm trying to stay away from using the `.xcodeproj` file. Please, someone let me know if this is possible. I'll paste a simple example below, but just know if there's a better way to handling configuration besides the code below, please submit as answer.

Example:

```
// main.swift

#if DEBUG
  print("Im in Debug!!")
#else
  print("Im in Release!!")
#endif
```

Comment: So when you say stay away from using .xcodeproj you mean setting a `DEBUG` variable in build settings?

Comment: @boidkan yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Swift 3.1, the Package Manager doesn't offer the option to customize build settings in the `Package.swift` file (this feature is part of the team's [roadmap for Swift 4](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2017-January/000307.html)). However, you can use the `-Xswiftc` flag to pass custom build settings to the compiler when you invoke `swift build` or `swift test`.

To set the `DEBUG` flag in debug mode, invoke `swift build` like this:

```
swift build --configuration debug -Xswiftc "-D" -Xswiftc "DEBUG"
```

And for release builds you would do the usual:

```
swift build --configuration release
```

There is also `-Xlinker` and `Xcc` to pass flags to the linker and C compiler, respectively.